# Simple SQL JOIN returns no result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'am trying to execute a simple Join, but I can't figure out why the result is empty.

```
select * from 
technical_center.subprozess as a  join
technical_center.zrel_schleifprozess_subprozess as b on 
a.subprozess_id = b.Subprozess_subprozess_id_g;
```

Of course I checked the data in the tables. Every row in the relation table has a partner in the 'Subprozess' table.

Any Idea what could cause the empty result?

[image]

Comment: If there were matches, you would get results.  Hence, there are no matches.  You are using strings, so perhaps there are hidden characters or spaces that prevent the matching.

Comment: you may have collation difference between the tables. Same strings with different collations may not match. please check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-literal.html

Comment: Oh sure, "I checked the data in the tables". [mcve] please.

Comment: we have no way to reliably reproduce your conditions/observations investigate hints above (hidden chars and/or collations)